# Anylogic - Problem by Creating Schedule and ResourcePool programmatically

Tags: anylogic, schedule

Hier's the task, the agent "Machine" will be created programmatically via a excel data, and I need to create ResourcePool and Schedule for each machine programmatically which will set in a Service block.
I create two Variables and a function to create Schedule and ResourcePool like:
```
v_Workershift = new Schedule();

````
v_Workershift.setOwner(this);
v_Workershift.setCalendarType(true);
v_Workershift.setFirstDayOfWeek(MONDAY);
v_Workershift.setPeriod(1);
v_Workershift.setTimeUnits(DAY.toMilliseconds());
v_Workershift.setGlueIntervals(true);
v_Workershift.addInterval(1, 1, 6, 0, 0, 1, 1, 14, 0, 0, true);
v_Workershift.initialize(); 
//Create ResourcePool and Put the schedule"v_Workershift" into ResourcePool(v_WorkersPool)
v_WorkersPool = new ResourcePool();
v_WorkersPool.set_capacityDefinitionType(ResourcePool.CapacityDefinitionType.CAPACITY_SCHEDULE_ON_OFF);
v_WorkersPool.set_capacityScheduleOnOff(v_Workershift);
```
````

The function runs in the Agent "Machine" Startup and the setting in service like:
[enter image description here][1]

And there's the Problem:

there's a error by running the model:

````
```
Error during model startup:
root.pop_Machines[0].r_Workers:
Parameter capacityScheduleOnOff is not specified (null/empty)
```
````

Have i write the code correctly or i make a misstake by setting in the service block.

And could someone give me a advice, how to use the Help correctly, wenn i need to create another block programmaticly, i can only find some code in Forum, but not in Help.

Thank you very very much for your answer!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTEKb.png

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to note here:

1. The error specifically mentions `root.pop_Machines[0].r_Workers` - it seems that this object still doesn't have a reference to the programmatically created **Schedule** object. In the first code snippet provided the **Schedule** object is set into `v_WorkersPool` object.
2. Creating objects programmatically is generally not advisable in AnyLogic. Things such as **Schedule** is fine because they're more or less standalone. However a **ResourcePool** is fairly complex and requires a fair bit of housekeeping to make sure it is created and registered correctly. Why is it necessary to create it programmatically?

---

**Update**

A better way to do this is to:

1. Put the new **Schedule** `v_Workershift` into a collection called *schedules*
2. Create a population of **ResourcePool** blocks (call it *resources*). Then instead of doing `v_WorkersPool = new ResourcePool();` you can use `v_WorkersPool = add_resources()` which will create a **ResoucePool** and will also take care of all the housekeeping
3. Have the *v_WorkersPool* get **Schedule** from that *schedules* collection

Comment: I need to create an automatic model generation through Anylogic. That is, Excel to provide the input data, anylogic to implement the model building, The model is then run through Python or Java and automatically export the output into a Excel. The production system is then optimised. 
The workingshift of workers are an important input data for the system, so i need to create schedule programmaticlly. 
Perhaps, could you please give me some advice, what mistakes did I make in creating the workingshift programmaticlly.